# How to setup Kafka consume application dependency on batch process

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing a consumer application using spring-kafka. I am planning to keep it running by 24*7 using pod. But, recently I got to know there are some batch processes which would be running in between. And, when those batches are running, our processing shouldn't occur. So, probably, somehow I have to stop polling for records and when the batches are finished then I can resume my processing. But, I have no clue how to achieve this..

Whether the batches are running or not, I can query and get the details from table, by looking into some flag. But, how can I stop polling for records ? and will it not cause re balancing if I just keep consumer application running without processing anything ?

**Config class :**

```java
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory(){
        
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,KAFKA_BROKERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OFFSET_RESET);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_RECORDS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_INTERVAL);
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SSL_PROTOCOL);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_TRUSTSTORE_SECURE);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEYSTORE_SECURE);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEY_SECURE);
        
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);    
    }
    
    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> 
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
 
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory =
                            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
      factory.setConcurrency(KAFKA_CONCURRENCY);
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE); // manual async comm
   
      return factory;
  }
```

**Code :**

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic}", groupId = "${app.group_id_config}")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgement) throws Exception {

        try {   
                int flag = getBatchIndquery ();
                // How to stop and resume based on the flag value---?
                
                
                
                // business logic process once the consumer resumes
                processRecords();
                InsertDb();
            
            acknowledgement.acknowledge();
                    
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(record);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the endpoint registry to stop and start the container...

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myListener" ...)
```

```java
@Autowired
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
...

registry.getListenerContainer("myListener").stop();
```

See [@KafkaListener Lifecycle Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle).

> The listener containers created for @KafkaListener annotations are not beans in the application context. Instead, they are registered with an infrastructure bean of type KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry. This bean is automatically declared by the framework and manages the containers' lifecycles; it will auto-start any containers that have autoStartup set to true. All containers created by all container factories must be in the same phase. See Listener Container Auto Startup for more information. You can manage the lifecycle programmatically by using the registry. Starting or stopping the registry will start or stop all the registered containers. Alternatively, you can get a reference to an individual container by using its id attribute. You can set autoStartup on the annotation, which overrides the default setting configured into the container factory. You can get a reference to the bean from the application context, such as auto-wiring, to manage its registered containers.